# Intent somehow goes back to first page

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a button which adds a value to the database and intents to the second page.

And it works on the emulator and on most phones except it goes back to the first screen on an Oppo Phone.

Why would that happen?

Here is how my code looks like.

```
    test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                myDB.inserttojobs("test",jobdate);
                Intent newinent = new Intent(AddJob.this, AddJob2.class);
                intent.putExtra("JobID","test");


                startActivity(newinent);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(AddJob.this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
}
```

Comment: there is nothing wrong with this code.add your signature activity

Comment: @BishoyAbd rest of the code is in here - https://codeshare.io/G6dJZz

Comment: first screen is what activity ?

Comment: First screen is the Login page. It just has a Edittext field and a button which checks if the password is correct and then navigates to this page.

Comment: Did it display errors ?

Comment: @JohnJoe no errors, nothing at all. Just navigates back to the first page.

Comment: Possibly your app is getting crashed and your phone is opening origin Actviity. This happens in some phones. Check your error logs. Above snippet looks fine.

Comment: Are you doing DB insert in the UI thread??